# How do I delete resources that have been applied with kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, cert-manager, kustomize

I have to upgrade cert-manager on GKE cluster and due to the big version gap I have to uninstall and re-install it. Basically, I am wondering how should I uninstall it and since I installed it through kustomization file I thought I will do the same with the uninstallation.
The question is: is it possible or not?

I also want to know if I can delete the manifests all together or there's an order? eg: delete controller before deleting the CRDs.

> ```
> apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: Kustomization
>
> resources:
>   - crds/clusterissuers.crd.yaml
>   - crds/issuers.crd.yaml
>   - crds/challenges.crd.yaml
>   - crds/certificaterequests.crd.yaml
>   - crds/orders.crd.yaml
>   - crds/certificates.crd.yaml
>
>
>   - operator/cainjector
>   - operator/webhook
>   - operator/controller
> ```

Comment: How did you apply the manifests you built with kustomize?

Comment: To build manifests, I run the docker image :  docker run --mount src=<full-path to your manifests>,target=/path,type=bind \
    --mount src=<full-path to my gcloud default credentials>,target=/var/google/credentials.json,type=bind \
    -it \
    eu.gcr.io/workspace/kustomize \
    /path/<sub path to the folder that includes your kustomization file>

Comment: What commands to run within the docker container? Are you doing `kustomize build` followed by `kubectl apply -f`?

Comment: yes! that's the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to uninstall it by running `kustomize build 'folder' | kubectl delete -f -`.

Kustomize will remove the resources in order, so I would remove first the operators and later the CRDs as cleanup.